# Paypal sandbox не присылает ipn уже 2 дня

Tags: paypal, sandbox

Здравствуйте! Кто сталкивался с подобным? На stackoverflow.com прочитал, что такое бывает на стороне PayPal. Мне нужно как-то закончить тестирование , а они не приходят( Код валидный на 100%. При отправке тэстового IPN все принимает. В чем проблема ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как Вариант:** проверьте адрес IPN.

Валидный адрес: http://test.com/?action=ipn

Невалидный адрес: http://test.com?action=ipn

Сам пол дня потратил что-бы разобраться.

**Кроме:** verify запросы должны выполняться через https